# Obtaining File Format in Java/ DOS-UNIX

Tags: java, unix, file, format, dos

Is there an easy way to see whether particular file has DOS/MAC/UNIX line endings?

Currently I read the file byte by byte and stop if I see Windows carriage return

```
for (byte thisByte : bytes) {

  if ((!isDos) && (thisByte == 13)) {
      isDos = true;
  }
...
```

Is there a way to get the same information without reading file byte by byte?

Comment: Note that stopping on CR (`'\r'` or `13`) does not distinguish between Mac and DOS.  You need to look at the next character to tell if it is Mac or DOS — if it is newline (`'\n'`), then you have DOS; if it is not, it is Mac; and if you come across newline before CR, then you have Unix.  And that's the bare minimum checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible optimization might be to look only at the very final one or two bytes of the file.  Since many text files terminate in a line ending this should work most of the time.  If you don't spot a line ending there, then you'll have to fall back to byte-by-byte.

BTW, your example code sets isDos to true without checking if the very next character is a decimal 10.  If it isn't a 10 then it's probably a MAC file format.

Comment: That is valid. In my small world only DOS or UNIX formats may make an appearance. I will make a change to make code more generic and include MAC. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's a text file, and the lines are "reasonable" length, you could read a large block of the file (say 4096 bytes) and scan just that block for the CR character.

But otherwise, no, the only way that you can find a character in a file is to actually read the entire file and look for the character.

On the assumption that you're asking this question because you have performance problems reading the file a byte at a time: make sure that you wrap the `FileInputStream` with a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an example of reading a portion of a file? Or, do you mean "stop reading after having read 4096 bytes?)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a file only uses one sort of end-of-line, then you can just scan for the first newline and see if it's DOS/UNIX/Mac.

Comment: right. that's what i am currently doing, after heaving read file line by line. I wonder if there is an easier, more elegant way to get the same information

Comment: From your code it looks like you read the whole file if it isn't DOS.